# See my messages on Kafka with my Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

How Can I see my messages produced by my Kafka Producer defined in my Spring Boot Application?

This is my Kafka Producer Configuration:

```
package com.nttdata.iotfw.iotcore.bus.kafka;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;

import com.nttdata.iotfw.iotcore.integration.config.ChannelConstants;

@Profile("!test")
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "kafka.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducer {

@Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
private String bootstrapServers;

@Value("${kafka.security.protocol:PLAINTEXT}")
private String securityProtocol;

@Value("${kafka.ssl.truststore.location:#{null}}")
private String trustStoreLocation;
@Value("${kafka.ssl.truststore.password:#{null}}")
private String trustStorePassword;

@Value("${kafka.ssl.keystore.location:#{null}}")
private String keyStoreLocation;

@Value("${kafka.ssl.keystore.password:#{null}}")
private String keyStorePassword;

@Bean("KafkaProducerHandler")
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = ChannelConstants.OUTBOUND_CHANNEL_NAME)
public MessageHandler handler(final KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) throws Exception {
    final KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> handler = new KafkaProducerMessageHandler<>(kafkaTemplate);
    handler.setAsync(true);
    return handler;
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate(final ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory) {
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    return kafkaTemplate;
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);

    // introduce a delay on the send to allow more messages to accumulate
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1);
    // security
    properties.put("security.protocol", securityProtocol);
    if ("SSL".equals(securityProtocol)) {
        properties.put("ssl.truststore.location", trustStoreLocation);
        properties.put("ssl.truststore.password", trustStorePassword);
        if ((keyStoreLocation != null) && !keyStoreLocation.isEmpty()) {
            properties.put("ssl.keystore.location", keyStoreLocation);
            properties.put("ssl.keystore.password", keyStorePassword);
        }
    }
    // set more properties
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(properties);
}
}
```

And this is my application-properties:

```
server.port: 8085
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/#123* spring.datasource.username=#123* spring.datasource.password=#123*
 
kafka.enabled=true mqtt.enabled=false
kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
```

Comment: You need a consumer... But maybe clarify how exactly you expect to see the data? Because you could also print the record before producing it

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this tool](https://github.com/obsidiandynamics/kafdrop)